# Travelling to UK as a dual-national, when your British Passport has expired?

Tags: uk, passports, dual-nationality

I am a South African (living in South Africa) with a British passport (Dual Nationality) I need to visit the UK in a few months time, but my British passport has expired. Can I enter the country with my South African Passport supported by my Certificate of naturalisation? Or where can I renew my Passport?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  How few is few?  You may be able to renew your UK passport.

Comment: Can someone explain what "endorsed" means in the passport context here: https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=GB&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GB&EM=ZA&TR=00&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#

Comment: I think when it says `endorsed British Citizen` it means that the expired passport needs to show you are British, and not something else (eg perhaps not British Subject)

Comment: you can always go to the UK on your SA passport and be granted a tourist visa on entry (or the SA equivalent) and then renew your UK passport while you are there

Comment: Edmund is wrong, SA citizens can't be granted a tourist visa on entry. They are required to apply in advance

Comment: @Karlson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_passport#Endorsements

Comment: I got my Brit passport renewed (overseas) in only 6 weeks this year. Give it a try. I gather if you pay more they do it quicker, but I didn't, and I thought 6 weeks was pretty good.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=GB&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GB&EM=ZA&TR=00&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#), you can enter Britain on an expired British passport, providing it is endorsed "British Citizen" (or some other endorsement indicating right of abode in the UK).

The idea is that all British citizens are allowed to enter Britain: they don't need permission, just proof of that status. An expired passport proves citizenship just as well as a valid one.

Comment: There's one little catch here.  If I renounce my British citizenship, I only have to surrender my current passport.  Technically, I should surrender an expired one, but I can claim to have lost it after I received a new one.  Then, purely theoretically, I can use this expired passport to enter Britain.

Comment: @AleksG If you report a passport as lost, it will be marked as such in the relevant databases, and if you attempt to present it to the Border Force you will have a very bad day.