# Traveling from Ireland to UK on a South African passport

Tags: visas, air-travel, uk, ireland, south-african-citizens

I have dual nationality ie a British and a South African passport. My British passport has expired I will be renew once in the UK.
I will be travelling from South Africa, into Dublin and on to Heathrow.

Do I need a visa using my South African passport commuting from IRELAND to UK?

Comment: Nothing has changed since you asked 14 days ago.  Is something in the original question/answers unclear?

Comment: I do understand your comment and question. My apologies for not explaining fully in my 2nd question. Thank you for your reply. Yes, the original questions were clear. I am unable to obtain a visa by the time I am due to fly. My question pertains to flying from Ireland into UK now, rather than flying direct from SA to UK. I am still concerned about customs on arrival in the UK?

Comment: I got it, it answers my concern of immigrations in the UK. My questions derived from the South African authorities saying I cannot fly to UK on my SA passport without a visa into the UK. Even though my expired British passport stipulates the right of abode and clause 12 in gov.uk.com on immigration and citizenship says I cannot apply for a visa for the UK if I am a British citizen. Travel agents and visa parties in South Africa do not 'get it". thankyou for your time and most importantly your valid and realistic advice which I shall share amongst South Africa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the airline. Some airlines require passports and if the only passport you have is South African, then you also need a visa to go with it.

However, not all transportation operators between Ireland and the UK require passports for British citizens -- several other forms of ID/documentation can also suffice. There's a (non-authoritative, possibly inaccurate) list [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area#Travel_between_the_UK_and_Ireland).

There shouldn't be any immigration control on *arrival* in London, due to the Common Travel Area.

Comment: Not quite - they arrive at gates where there is no immigration, but there is still customs. They're neither Domestic Gates, nor International Gates, they're ones setup specially for CTA!

Comment: And please see https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/262656/annexg.pdf

Comment: Thank you @Henning Makholm, my concern is going through customs on arrival in the UK.

Comment: @Tans: I'm not sure how _customs_ is relevant to your questions about passports. Are you planning to bring contraband in your luggage?

Comment: My apologies @Henning Makholm. Correction; going through  "immigrations" at Heathrow flying from Dublin. Can one too recommend an airline as per your first repy?

Comment: @Tans: You will have to read through the list yourself and see if you have something one of them would accept. (Which may be doubtful -- when I replied I had the impression that you were _resident_ in Ireland as a EU/EEA citizen, in which case plenty of those other IDs might be available to you even though your _passport_ happend to be expired).

Comment: According to the answer at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30177/travelling-to-uk-as-a-dual-national-when-your-british-passport-has-expired, one can enter the UK with an expired british passport.

Comment: @phoog: Yes, but for the purpose of being allowed boarding in Dublin, the _airline_ may well have less lenient rules than actual UK immigration.